# completion-prefix-display-length doesn't work on my terminal.app

Tags: terminal, bash-completion

I've found a lot of questions on .inputrc, and the answers included people using Mac OS X terminal.app.

But I've set this property on and it didn't change readline's behaviour. I tried the same .inputrc on Ubuntu and it worked…

Is there some specific action I should take on terminal.app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I think I've finally cracked it.
I will answer my own question for future reference here:

Mac OS X uses editline (descendant from libedit that kinda emulates readline) instead of the more commom readline command line text handler.

I'm still learning how editline works, but I guess it isn't 100% compatible with readline's .inputrc.

So my completion-prefix-display-length attribute probably doesn't work with my version of OS X editline.

Answer (score 1):

So that was it indeed.
I've made the following test to prove my hypothesis:
I've compiled readline under Mac OS X and then run bash with the readline lib I've compiled (through [with-readline tool](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/2005/withreadline.html)).
It worked fine, all my inputrc attributes worked and I finished my questions.

So in Mac OS X readline is shadowed by editline (it still has readline.h includes and realine's dynamic libraries, but they are editline's code).